# Turning off iODBC tracing

Tags: macos, odbc, trace, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using iODBC on OS X 10.6.8 agains MySQL (mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.8) from a C program that I'm writing, but tracing of all ODBC library calls, which is supposed to be turned off by default, is turned on.

I have found a set of `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files in `/etc` and in `/Library/ODBC/`, but none of them contains "Trace = yes", and adding an `[ODBC]` section with "Tracing = no" to any of these files doesn't seem to do anything. I also do not have any private `.odbc.ini` or `.odbcinst.ini` files in the working directory nor in my home directory nor anywhere else.

The only way I can turn tracing off is to call `SQLSetConnectAttr()` to set `SQL_ATTR_TRACE` to `SQL_OPT_TRACE_OFF` after allocating a connection handle, but at that point, the trace file, `sql.log`, has already been created in the working directory.

Any help with tracking down where tracing is turned on (it's supposed to be off by default), alternatively, how to turn it off so that the log file never gets created, would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone else that may look at this: I resolved my issue with ODBC tracing by setting the `ODBCINI` environment variable to point to `$HOME/.odbc.ini` wherein i set `TRACE=0` in the `[ODBC]` section. This seems to work as expected. I still do not know why or where tracing was turned on when I didn't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would be using odbc instead of the standard connector, but have you tried setting the option for the TraceFile to /dev/null in odbc.ini.  This may at least remove the file if you can't get the Trace = OFF to work by itself.

```
[ODBC]
Trace = OFF
TraceFile = /dev/null
```

Don't have my Mac at the office to test this, but seems like it should work.

Comment: What do you mean with "the standard connector"? Do you mean using the MySQL C API? I'd like to be able to replace the database implementation that is used beneath my code, putting e.g. PostgreSQL or SQLite there instead of MySQL at some point in the future. That's why I use ODBC. Setting the trace file to `/dev/null` feels like a hack to me which might solve the problem (haven't had a chance to try it yet), but does so in a most clunky way. I'd like to understand why what's supposed to be the default setting (no trace) is not actually the default.

Comment: ODBC doesn't normalize the SQL differences among various database vendors.  You may want to look at using an ORM of some type and have that handle your database abstraction.  Then you can slide in optimized connectors for your brand of database at will.  I agree the above method may be considered a hack, but then again you did say that you wanted a minimum of turning the file creation off.  :-)  Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of an ORM that would work in a UNIX C application? A pointer would be welcome. I will accept your answer as it stands none the less. Thanks/

Comment: libdbi would be a good starting point.  Thanks and good luck with your project!

Comment: I'm now working with Oracle Template Library (OTL) in C++, accessing MySQL though its ODBC layer. I sorted out the tracing issue (see my comment to my question above). Thanks for your pointers none the less!

Answer (score 0):

The default settings files for ODBC on Mac OS X are found at --

```
/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
```

The first two are for system-level settings and DSNs; the latter are for user-level.

Some buggy installers and libraries create files at  --

```
/Users/*/.odbc.ini
/Users/*/.odbcinst.ini
/etc[/*]/.odbc.ini
/etc[/*]/.odbcinst.ini
/etc[/*]/odbc.ini
/etc[/*]/odbcinst.ini
```

These can lead to trouble.  This command will reveal all potentially trouble-making files --

```
sudo find / \( -name '.odbc*.ini' -or -name 'odbc*.ini' \) -ls
```

Best is to --

1. blend the content of existing non-default files into the default locations, and drop the non-default files
2. create symlinks from the buggy .odbc[inst].ini locations to the default files
3. update the [iODBC components on your Mac](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X)
4. enjoy trouble free ODBC use

(ObDisclaimer: I am an employee of [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), who maintain and support the [iODBC project](http://iodbc.org/), which is the ODBC Driver Manager chosen by Apple for Mac OS X, bundled since Jaguar (10.2.x).)